# access to global picklist value from apex or trigger

Tags: apex, upsert, global-picklist

How can we upsert data to global picklist value by using apex?

I wanna catch record data from custom object by soql in apex,
and upsert the data to global picklist value.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use the `GlobalValueSet` metadata, and it is [accessible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalvalueset.htm) via the Metadata API. 
To make updates to the metadata via apex, you can use the FinancialForce Metadata API Wrapper. [Here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) is the repo.

Having said that, be careful in doing this. you could introduce some unintented regression and can create data quality issues.

Comment: not to mention that the running user needs customize application privileges and that might cause security issues

Comment: good point @cropredy... s'pose the OP wanted to circumvent that in real time trigger, what would they do? For nonreal-time, a scheduled batch job running as a sys admin ought to do the trick

Comment: (1) use a platform event; runs as automated process user (might work, automated process user has some limitations); (2) do callout using named credentials where NC defines a user w/ customize app privileges